# Receiving string instead of the sting value

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement:

```
if (typeof herp === "undefined") {
        herp = $(".box .title").eq(0).text();
    }
```

This statement is work to true. However there are some time in which if I type in console.

Comment: `if (!herp)` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i'm right understood your question, some time if conditon execute at "" text

try this

```
if (herp) {
        herp = $(".box .title").eq(0).text();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function and use it when you want to check something similar:

```
function exist(text){
   text != null && text != ""
}
```

Usage:

```
if (exist(herp)) {
  herp = $(".box .title").eq(0).text();
}
```